# How to compile and link against MacPort's libstdc++ in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, std, macports, libstdc++

I just upgraded my gcc distribution through MacPorts, and I would like to use the last libstdc++4.7 (which supports a number of C++11 features I'm interested in) with Xcode's clang++. Obviously, activating the new gcc4.7 through the MacPorts's `select` command is not enough, since Xcode keeps complaining about missing headers, e.g.

```
#include<random>

'random' file not found
```

I have already set the an additional headers' directory (MacPorts default root `/opt/local/include`) and additional libraries directory (MacPorts default root `/opt/local/lib`), however it looks like Xcode is having a hard time recognizing that its C++ headers are in `/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++`.

Comment: Did this get solved? I need help with this also

Comment: have you verified select command with gcc -v and which gcc to see location of gcc compiler?